# Document Approval error message "This form cannot be opened in a web browser. To open this form, use Microsoft Infopath"

Tags: workflow, error, approval

I have a well-established Globally Reusable Workflow which has been working for a few years.  It now shows an error during approval.  Nothing has changed in the workflow or on the Document Library, the approvers also have not changed - I am the Sharepoint Administrator, I have one other colleague who also helps as SP Admin.  If something has changed in the settings, it would have been inadvertent.

The error message: "this form cannot be opened in a web browser.  To open this form, use Microsoft Infopath".  We don't use Infopath and the approval relates to a document rather than a custom item, so I'm puzzled by the unhelpful error message.

I followed [Coralie's Answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/my-browser-enabled-infopath-form-does-not-open-in-my-browser) but I this was not the cause, the Approver is in the Approver's group and has both **Contribute** and **Approve** permissions.

### Current Approval Method

- Globally reusable workflow.
- 'Publish Major version' of document triggers the approval process.

### Steps taken to resolve

- Cancelled document approval and resubmitted document for approval.  (Resulted in the same error message).

### Screen shots

[image: Error message pic]

### Research

MS Link - [troubleshooting guide](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35767.sharepoint-2013-this-form-cannot-be-opened-in-a-web-browser.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer - replaced it with a reusable workflow instead of a **globally** reusable workflow.

The globally reusable workflow had become corrupted, for reasons unknown...woooo spooky...